# How to raise an error when open a window ODOO?

Tags: python, odoo-8, raiseerror

I would like to know how to raise an error when I open a window in Odoo.
For example, I open Sales window, and it'll raise an error or warning like "Hello" or anything else.
I know to use exception like:

```
from openerp.osv import osv,fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp import pooler
from openerp.exceptions import except_orm`

raise osv.except_osv(_('Hello'), _('Hello World'))
```

but I don't know where should I put the code to raise that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `default_get` method, It will execute whenever click on the `CREATE` button.
2. Add a field in `list/form view` as `compute` field, and add `raise osv.except_osv(_('Hello'), _('Hello World'))` in compute function.
3. For a button action. define a function and call it in button definition.

   `<button name='function_name' type='object'/>`

Comment: how to raise that without click any button?
and about compute field, how it will look like? is can use if state == 'cancel' and then raise the exception?

Comment: Please mention when/where do you want to raise warning, and conditions if any. Also post  code that already you have tried.

Comment: Updated my answer